# C# code to find sum of column values in Excel

Tags: c#

I've got a DataTable like below,

```
EmpID   EETaxes    ERTaxes   NetPay

100      130.09    120.05    550.00

200      445.68    344.80    980.00

300      100.00    200.00    600.00
```

And I am exporting the DataTable to Excel,

My problem is that after exporting the data to Excel, I need to display sum(EETaxes) and sum(ERTaxes) and sum(NetPay).

Can anyone tell me the C# code to find the sum of the values in a column in Excel dynamically?

Comment: How are you exporting to excel? One method would be to calculate the values in C#, before exporting, another would be to export to excel with an extra row, containing the excel formula to sum the values. The hard part with the 2nd option would be working out the range of the sum function, which would depend on the number of rows you're exporting.

Comment: how are you exporting this table? do you create a csv file or what else? Answer depends on how you export.

Comment: So you must (1) export this data to Excel, then (2) calculate the sums in your application? Why then would you need Excel for (2), if you already have the data?

Answer (score 3):

**i** is **row**

and **j** is **column**

where u want to have sum calculated

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = "=SUM(B2:B" + i + ")";
```

you can set value of i and j programtically based on what is the last row

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "=SUM(B2:B" + i + ")";   
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 3] = "=SUM(C2:C" + i + ")";   
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 4] = "=SUM(D2:D" + i + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String Expr = "=SUM(J2:J" + end + ")";
activeSheet.get_Range("J" + (end + 1), "J" + (end + 1)).Cells[1, 1] = Expr;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO ! Please feel free to add some sentences to explain things.

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

How you export your DataTable to Excel? In most of the case you can not write an expression(function) other than a value to excel. You may compute and add a sum row in DataTable  before export to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Some important issue about @codemirrors solution: 
if someone with e.g. a german located version of Excel opens the file:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "=SUM(B2:B" + i + ")";
```

wont work because the function is localized too:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "=SUMME(B2:B" + i + ")";
```